# Color change on react not working after a while

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a color changer on react from pressing a button. But one issue it faces is that after a few clicks, it stops working. Can anyone help with this?

```js
import './App.css';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Button from './components/Button'



function App() {

  const [color, setColor] = useState("yellow")
  const colorPalette = ['#FF6633', '#FFB399', '#FF33FF', '#FFFF99', '#00B3E6', 
  '#E6B333', '#3366E6', '#999966', '#99FF99', '#B34D4D',
  '#80B300', '#809900', '#E6B3B3', '#6680B3', '#66991A', 
  '#FF99E6', '#CCFF1A', '#FF1A66', '#E6331A', '#33FFCC',
  '#66994D', '#B366CC', '#4D8000', '#B33300', '#CC80CC', 
  '#66664D', '#991AFF', '#E666FF', '#4DB3FF', '#1AB399',
  '#E666B3', '#33991A', '#CC9999', '#B3B31A', '#00E680', 
  '#4D8066', '#809980', '#E6FF80', '#1AFF33', '#999933',
  '#FF3380', '#CCCC00', '#66E64D', '#4D80CC', '#9900B3', 
  '#E64D66', '#4DB380', '#FF4D4D', '#99E6E6', '#6666FF'];

  let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)

return (
    <div style = {{backgroundColor: color, height: 300}}>
      <button onClick = {() => setColor(colorPalette[randomNum])}>Click me to change color!</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

It will work until there's a collision. A collision occurs when the previous value in `randomNum` is the same as a new one. This means the new value stored in `color` state will be the same as its old state. When the state is unchanged, React won't re-render the component `App`. Now, since the random number generation relies on the `App` component being re-rendered, a new value for `randomNum` won't be generated.

Helps to think like so: here the component is a function, every (re-)render is equivalent to calling that function. Now, if the function isn't called, `randomNum` won't get a new value assigned to it. That in turn will not trigger a re-render.

**Solution**

Generate a new random value upon each click. Create a function to do that and call it upon every click of the button. Full working demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-color-change-random-let-onej90?file=/src/App.js). Code of interest below.

```
const genRandomNum = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)

return (
...
<button onClick={() => setColor(colorPalette[genRandomNum()])}>
  Click me to change color!
</button>
...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing event handler inline ,create separate function for the event handler like below

```
 const handleClick = () => {
    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
    setColor(colorPalette[randomNum]);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: color, height: 300 }}>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me to change color!</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Why your code were not working because when number generator logic return the same number ,then re-render does not happens and because of that new number will not get generated

Answer (score -1):

you have 50 colours and a random number may return 60 and in return, it will pass undefined, first, you should set the range of your random colour between 0 and 49 to get correct color range

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}
```